# What is the connection, if any, between 'adapt' and 'adept'?

Tags: etymology

The English adjective ***adept*** originates from the classical Latin adjective *adeptus*, to describe a person who has obtained knowledge of alchemy, magic and the occult.

The verb ***to adapt*** would appear superficially to have a quite different etymology, deriving from the Latin verb ***adaptāre***. However in the description of the etymology the OED says **'to perhaps compare *adept***'

**So what is the link between *adept*, *adapt*, *adopt* etc.?** Is there a Latin scholar out there who understands this?

> Etymology:  < adapt v. or its etymon classical Latin adaptāre, by
>   analogy with adjectives derived from Latin past participle stems which
>   were identical to the verb stem, as e.g. content adj.2, distract adj.,
>   erect adj.; **perhaps compare also adept adj**. The past participle of
>   classical Latin adaptāre is in fact adaptātus. Compare post-classical
>   Latin adaptus (7th cent.; rare). Similar motivation may have
>   determined the earlier formations adaption n., adaptly adv., adaptness
>   n.; compare also adapted adj.  (**Oxford English Dictionary**)

Answer (score 2):

The common root is **apt** from which both adept and adapt derive, adoption seems to have a different origin:

[Adapt](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Adapt&searchmode=none):

> - early 15c. (implied in adapted) "to fit (something, for some purpose)," from Middle French adapter (14c.), from Latin adaptare "adjust," from ad- "to" (see ad-) + aptare "join," from aptus "fitted" **(see apt)**. Meaning "to undergo modification so as to fit new circumstances" (intransitive) is from 1956. Related: Adapting.

[Adept](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Adept&searchmode=none):noun

> - "an expert," especially "one who is skilled in the secrets of anything," 1660s, from Latin adeptus **(see adept (adj.)).** The Latin adjective was used as a noun in this sense in Medieval Latin among alchemists.

Adept (adjective)

> - 1690s, "completely skilled" from Latin adeptus "having reached, attained," past participle of adipisci "to come up with, arrive at," figuratively "to attain to, acquire," from ad- "to" (see ad-) + apisci "grasp, attain," related to aptus "fitted" **(see apt)**. Related: Adeptly.

[Apt](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=apt&allowed_in_frame=0):

> - mid-14c., "inclined, disposed;" late 14c., "suited, fitted, adapted," from Old French ate (13c., Modern French apte), or directly **from Latin aptus "fit, suited," adjectival use of past participle of *apere "to attach, join, tie to,"** from PIE root *ap- (1) "to grasp, take, reach" (cognates: Sanskrit apnoti "he reaches," Latin apisci "to reach after, attain," Hittite epmi "I seize"). Elliptical sense of "becoming, appropriate" is from 1560s.

[Adoption](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=adopt&searchmode=none):

> - **c.1500, a back-formation from adoption or else from Middle French adopter or directly from Latin adoptare "take by choice, choose for oneself, select, choose"** (especially a child). Originally in English also of friends, fathers, citizens, etc. Sense of "to legally take as one's own child" and that of "to embrace, espouse" a practice, method, etc. are from c.1600.

(Etymonline)

Comment: +1. But I think you would find it interesting to take a look at the way the two words are described in the OED. They do not specifically make the connection with *apt*, though the classical Latin connections are close. I am wondering which source you used. was it *Etymoline*?

Comment: Unluckily I don't have access to OED. Anyway the Latin roots they are referring  to may be those of APT ( from Latin aptus "fit, suited," adjectival use of past participle of *apere "to attach, join, tie to) from which both terms derive!!